# Incorrect float result

Tags: c, arrays, floating-point, initialization, average

I have a list of numbers in a float array (see bellow) which i have to get the sum and then calculate the average. Using this code for example:

```
for(i=0; i<M; i++)
    sI_Ssum += sI_S[i];
```

and print the result:

```
fprintf(fswaps, "Avg: %.1f", sI_Ssum/M);
```

I get this weird result which is obvious wrong, but why this happens?

```
75157066131085846000000000000000.0
```

All variables are float.

Array Elements:

```
224230368  
224013664  
223660880  
226627536  
225013760  
224190272  
223501872  
225202688  
224685264  
225468864  
226371200  
224903232  
226204800  
224598128  
225268816  
225997904  
225491536  
224665840  
226138784  
224613424
```

Comment: Are you sure your array is typed as float and not double? Double requires the %g format specifier.

Comment: Did you set `sI_Ssum` to `0.` before starting to add up?

Comment: @1s and 0s: "Double requires the %g format specifier"??? No, it doesn't. While it is a better idea to use `%lf` with `double` for consistency, `%f` will also work perfectly fine.

Comment: @1sand0s: This is not correct. At least from C99 on `printf & friends` promote `float`s to `double`s.

Comment: Yes i'm sure. I have other arrays too and the results are printed correctly using the same method.

Comment: Also: `sI_Ssum/(double)M`to avoid integer division. Show your variable's declarations.

Comment: No i didnt set the variable to 0. Let me try it

Comment: @DrKoch: If `sI_Ssum` is declared a floating point no integer devision is performed.

Comment: @alk I guess %f is okay. I've always used %g for doubles.

Comment: @RoastedCode: If you forgot to initialize the sum with zero, why are you so sure that those "other arrays" worked properly? Did you actually check the results?

Comment: @AnT Because the results seemed okay statistically. (Based on some specific sorting algorithms).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have forgotten to initialize `sI_Ssum`.

Set  `sI_Ssum` to `0` -

```
 sI_Ssum = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems i have to stop this habbit forgetting to initialize variables.

Comment: Yes, Initializing variable is always a good practice. Rather the variable initial value may set to a garbage value which produces uncertain results.